# Typo3 with realurl: rewrite /feed.rss to /index.php?id=33&type=777

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, realurl

I created a typeNum 777 with a RSS Feed. What I want to achieve now is that the feed can be reached via 
http://www.domain.com/feed.rss instead of http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=33&type=777

I have realurl installed but I don't seem to be able to configure it in this way. I have been trying for hours without progress. I tried the following in my realurl_conf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
'_DEFAULT' => array(
    'fileName' => array(
        'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
        'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
        'index' => array(
            'page.html' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    'type' => 1,
                )
            ),
            'feed.rss' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    'id' => 33,
                    'type' => 777
                )
            ),
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'keyValues' => array()
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

but when I use this an try domain.com/feed.rss I get redirected to the start page of my typo3 project. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think that ``'id' => 33`` is valid, the page must be set in the url. i.e. ``http://domain.com/news/feed.rss`` where "news" is a page. Maybe it's easier to solve this with a rewrite rule in your .htaccess

Comment: I tried that too but I couldn't get it to work - do you have an example for me? how can I achieve that without typo3 / realurl screwing with my rewrite rule

Comment: ``RewriteRule ^feed.rss$ /index.php?id=33&type=777 [L]`` Put this before the rules that handles the index.php rewrite. I am unable to test right now.

Comment: I tried that, right after the RewriteEngine On line, and it doesn't work. If I call the feed.rss, I get a typo3 error: File "feed.rss" was not found

Answer (score 0):

well, since I couldn't find an answer to my problem, I decided to go about it a little differently and settled for http://www.domain.com/rss/new-articles 
I did this via defining a preVars type ('rss' => 777). 
I posted a more detailed answer here: http://www.ophidia.net/insane/blog/?lang=en